unauthorized: Invalid clientid or client secret. Container registry Azure
I upload the image to the Azure DevOps pipeline, but it gives the following error:

##[error]unauthorized: Invalid clientid or client secret.
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1


deployment.yaml
apiVersion : apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: otmcarga 
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: otmcarga
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: otmcarga 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: otmcarga 
          image: acrotmdev.azurecr.io/otmcarga
          ports:
          - containerPort: 80
          env:
          - name: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE
            value: "dev"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 60

services.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: otmcarga
spec:
    type: LoadBalancer
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
    selector:
        app: otmcarga

It worked normally before... I wanted to deploy the docker image in the  Container Registry.

Glad to see you in Stack Overflow. The error unauthorized: Invalid clientid or client secret indicates the service connection in DevOps task is invalid now, please try to create a new one, give same access and replace in task for a check. Please  share the DevOps yaml content, and Dockerfile for troubleshooting.

May i know if it works after updating with a new service connection? If it persists, please share the pipeline yaml and Dockerfile for further troubleshooting.

To use service principle in Azure DevOps.

Go to Project settings>service connections in Azure devops.
Click new Connection and search docker container registry
Select Azure Container registry.
Select `service principle in Authentication>fill details> Give a name to Service Connection and save it.



Use the service connection login command.


Bellow yml file worked for me.
trigger:
- main
 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'login'
    containerRegistry: Registry connection
    
- task: Docker@2
  inputs:
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
    repository: azurepyimage
    tags: $(Build.BuildId)

OUTPUT:


